# Is it legal to mention a real newspaper in a fictional book / novel?

Tags: international

I'm writing my first novel. And I'm curious if it is legal for me to mention a real newspaper like "New York Times" or "The Daily Herald" in a fictional horror / thriller novel without getting sued.

Answer (score 3):

You can, and many authors and other creators of fiction do, use the names of real newspapers, real brands and products, and real people without obtaining permission from anyone.

As long as those names are not being used to market or identify goods or services, the use cannot be trademark infringement.

There idea that you cannot "defame the brans" is in fact much narrower than many people think, and than it used to be. Particularly in the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) free speech rights often supersede protections against so-called trademark "defamation". In the US all of the examples in the answer by Jack Edwards would be clearly legal, an they probably would be in many other countries as well, if they appeared in a work that was clearly fictional.

If a work mof fiction uses the name of a real person, and other identifying details that make it clear just which real person is being mentioned, **and** if statements that seem to be statements of fact, not opinion are made about that person, **and** if those statements are false and negative, **and** if a hypothetical reasonable person would believe that those statements are about the real person, not a fictional person, thereby harming that person's reputation, **then** if all that is true, the person might have a valid claim of defamation.

Comment: Yep: you were right, I was mostly wrong. However, I still think that using a product in a different manner than intended could be grounds for a suit.

Comment: @Jack Edwards I am not sure what you mean by "*using a product in a different manner than intended*". Authors have frequently made negative references to brands using their trademarks, and in some cases trademark owners have sued and lost. There is now a whole tradition of "sucks sites" that is sites with URLs like BrandXSucks.com hosting criticism of BrandX, not even fiction, but actual negative comment seriously intended, and there have been multiple US court rulings that such sites are not trademark infringements and are protected free speech. I am not as sure abut such sites elsewhere.

Comment: @Dale except in cases of defamation *per se* I think a plaintiff must show **actual** harm to reputation, and thus present a witness who actually believed the false statement, or show some evidence that someone did, at least in most US states, but I am not sure enough to revert your edit.

Comment: @JackEdwards why?  How does using the New York Times to start a fire, or Coca Cola to extinguish one, or publishing a fictional story in which someone does either of those things, infringe trademark rights?  Does it confuse consumers?

Comment: There are quite a few cases where (famous) people have appeared in movies or films as themselves. For example you might have a _real_ newsreader in a zombie movie, telling people on TV in his own newsshow about a zombie outbreak. To make it realistic.

Comment: @gnasher729  That is very true, but I don't see how it is relevant to this question, which deals with use of real names without permission.

Comment: I only questioned that usage because I know for sure that there are such restrictions regarding product placement in the film industry. I could be wrong, but I wouldn’t be surprised if the same logic could be applied to literature.